# Deserialise OData nested response

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have json (odata response) that looks like below and I am trying to deserialize it in C#. The response looks like below:

```
 {
"d": {
"results": [
    {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "http://localhost:7305",
            "uri": "http://localhost:7305",
            "type": "Subject.Classifications"
        },
        "dateTime": "2020-06-25T11:31:51",
        "source": "JHGTY",
        "body": "The offering has now increased ",
        "subject": "Offering- updated",
        "fees": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "week": "1",
                        "amount":"90.00" 
                    },
                    {
                      "week":"2",
                      "amount":"90.00" 
                    }
                    ]
              }

        "Error": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "http://localhost:7305/"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "http://localhost:7305",
            "uri": "http://localhost:7305",
            "type": "Subject.Classifications"
        },
        "dateTime": "2020-06-26T11:25:51",
        "source": "XFGFT",
        "body": "The offering has now degraded ",
        "subject": "Offering- updated",
        "Error": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "http://localhost:7305/"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
}
```

I am using following code to deserialize it using newtonsoft:

```
dynamic notifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);
```

I have created models like below and able to deserialise it and can get the results.

```
    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("d")]
        public D D { get; set; }
    }

    public class D
    {
        [JsonProperty("results")]
        public List<Student> Results { get; set; }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public string body{ get; set; }
        public string subject{ get; set; }
        public List<Fee> fees { get; set; }
    }
    public class Fee
    {
        public string week{ get; set; }
        public string amount{ get; set; }
        
    }
```

when when I try to get fees array I am getting  following error but if if I remove the fees property from the student class it works fine.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[genie.Api.Controllers.ClassificationController+Classifications]' 
because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON, fees is an object and not an array. You are missing a class,

Update your Fees class to this to make it work,

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("d")]
    public D D { get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<Student> Results { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public string body { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public Fees fees { get; set; }
}
public class Fees
{
    public List<Fee> results { get; set; }
}

public class Fee
{
    public string week { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
}
```

and with the above classes, you should be able to deserialize correctly,

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Also noticed you were missing a comma before your `Error` property... probably a copy paste thing.

```
"fees": {
  "results": [
    {
      "week": "1",
      "amount": "90.00"
    },
    {
      "week": "2",
      "amount": "90.00"
    }
  ]
}, // Here, you need to place a comma.
"Error": {
  "__deferred": {
    "uri": "http://localhost:7305/"
  }
}
```

Comment: @jawad...I tried it and it didn't crash but results are empty. Do I have to but some attribute on the property like [JsonProperty("results")]?

Comment: @Jawad..please ignore my previous comment as your solution is working correctly..my bad as the odata expand attribute was set incorrectly.